# laravel-admin не могу настроить обращение к поддериктории

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6

Здравтсвуйте, такая проблема: Я работаю с сервером на виртуалке и обращение к админке у меня идет http://192.168.0.249/laravel-blog/admin/, c этим проблем нет, но внутри админки все ссылки ведут на http://192.168.0.249/admin/.

Попытка изменить конфиг admin.rout.prefix='laravel-blog/admin' не приводит к желаемому результату. Может кто уже сталкивался с такой проблемой, просьба отпишитесь. К слову сказать, на voyager и laraadmin такой проблемы нет.

Comment: А как у вас организованы роуты? Или может вы какой-то пакет используете под админку? Опишите, пожалуйста, подробнее.

Comment: Если вы сами пишете админку, то вам следует воспользоваться группами роутов одним из рекомендуемых способов: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-groups

Comment: да, действительно, я забыл упомянуть что я использую админку laravel-admin - http://laravel-admin.org/

Comment: http://laravel-admin.org/docs/#/en/quick-start?id=add-route - правьте роуты в указанном в доках файле.